# Page Blank on Load for React Tutorial

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I'm currently following [this react tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-on-the-server-for-beginners-build-a-universal-react-and-node-app) and I'm on the "[Playing with the single page app](https://scotch.io/tutorials/react-on-the-server-for-beginners-build-a-universal-react-and-node-app#playing-with-the-single-page-app)" section. When I run the simple web server as instructed and go to the corresponding address on my browser, I see a completely blank page with only this on the console:

```
bundle.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: ReactDOM is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:1)
    at t (bundle.js:1)
    at bundle.js:1
    at bundle.js:1
```

My files are here: https://github.com/Joonpark13/react-tutorial

Points of note:

- instead of compiling with the instruction as described in the tutorial (NODE_ENV=production node_modules/.bin/webpack -p) for production, I just used "webpack" (when I actually run the server, I use the command exactly as described on the tutorial).
- instead of separating app-client.js, routes.js, and AppRoutes.js into three separate files as described in the tutorial, I've combined all of them into AppRoutes.js.

I'm absolutely baffled as to why nothing is showing when I navigate to the specified address!

**Selected Relevant Files:**

AppRoutes.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Route, IndexRoute, Router, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Layout from './Layout';
import IndexPage from './IndexPage';
import AthletePage from './AthletePage';
import NotFoundPage from './NotFoundPage';

class AppRoutes extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const routes = (
            <Route path="/" component={Layout}>
                <IndexRoute component={IndexPage} />
                <Route path="athlete/:id" component={AthletePage} />
                <Route path="*" component={NotFoundPage} />
            </Route>
        );

        return (
            <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} onUpdate={() => window.scrollTo(0, 0)} />
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<AppRoutes />, document.getElementById('main'));
```

webpack.config.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'components', 'AppRoutes.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'static', 'js'),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
            loader: ['babel-loader'],
            query: {
                cacheDirectory: 'babel_cache',
                presets: ['react', 'es2015']
            }
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
            'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)
        }),
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.OccurenceOrderPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: { warnings: false },
            mangle: true,
            sourcemap: false,
            beautify: false,
            dead_code: true
        })
    ]
};
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Judo Heroes - A Universal JavaScript demo application with React</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="main"></div>

    <script src="/js/bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I downloaded your git files, ran npm install, ran npm build then ran npm start and the app is working fine for me. Are your files different in any way from those on git?

Comment: What your browser shows when you visit `http://localhost:port/js/bundle.js`?

Comment: try to run `npm install` again

Comment: It's always paths. Is your bundle actually at '/js/bundle.js'? Do you know what path.join is doing in your web pack config? Might want to investigate that.

Comment: It seems running npm install again worked! Thank you.

Comment: @xiaofan2406, please provide an answer so the question can be resolved.